# Nav Bar List Items Move Right With Hover

Tags: css, html, navigation

I have a nav bar where all the list elements have a padding of 25 px. When hovered over, the background color changes over the list element and adds a padding of 5px. However, the original padding adds on the 5px when hovered over, so the padding merges to 30px with a hover.

This changes the li elements in that they shift over those 5 px. I would like the li elements to remain static when hovered over, but still expand the padding when hovered.

I have tried changing to position:absolute but that did not help. Any advice on removing the extra padding while adding the 'hover padding' would be appreciated.

JS Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/j77mqm6q/

**Live Demo of HTML and CSS:**

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    background-image: url("subtle_white_feathers.png");
    text-align: justify;
}
/* NAVIGATION */

nav {
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 25px;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li a:visited {
    color: #669966;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #669966;
    color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transition: .25s linear;
    -moz-transition: .25s linear;
    transition: .25s linear;
    padding: 5px;
}
nav ul li a:active {
    background-color: #000000;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
/* DROPDOWN MENUS (ul > li > ul > li) */

ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    text-align: initial;
    font-color: #81B981;
}
ul li ul li {
    background: #444444;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 150px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
    margin-left: 25px;
    width: 50;
    font-color: #FFFFFF;
}
ul li ul li:first-child {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
ul li ul li:last-child {
    border: none;
}
ul li ul li:hover {
    background: #6A6B6D;
}
ul li ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #6A6B6D;
}
ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">About</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">History</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">What You Need to Know</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Getting Started</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Tools</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Background</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Build</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">WP Theme Anatomy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Putting it Together</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Files</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Sharing Your Theme</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Resources</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Guides</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Videos</a></li>
                </ul>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </nav>
    </div>
</body>
```

WHERE THE ISSUE LIES

```
nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 25px;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #669966;
    color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transition: .25s linear;
    -moz-transition: .25s linear;
    transition: .25s linear;    
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Did my answer end up working for you? Did you run into any issues that we might be able to help with?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that uses the `::before` pseudo-selector and absolute positioning to achieve the effect you're looking for without shifting the positions of the elements:

**Live Demo:**

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    background-image: url("subtle_white_feathers.png");
    text-align: justify;
}
/* NAVIGATION */

nav {
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 25px;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul li a:visited {
    color: #669966;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}
nav ul li a:hover::before {
    background-color: #669966;
    top: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    bottom: -5px;
    right: -5px;
}
nav ul li a:active {
    background-color: #000000;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
nav ul li a::before {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: .25s linear;
    -moz-transition: .25s linear;
    transition: .25s linear;
}
/* DROPDOWN MENUS (ul > li > ul > li) */

ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    text-align: initial;
    font-color: #81B981;
}
ul li ul li {
    background: #444444;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 150px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
    margin-left: 25px;
    width: 50;
    font-color: #FFFFFF;
}
ul li ul li:first-child {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
ul li ul li:last-child {
    border: none;
}
ul li ul li:hover {
    background: #6A6B6D;
}
ul li ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #6A6B6D;
}
ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">About</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">History</a></li>
                <li><a href="">What You Need to Know</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Getting Started</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Tools</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Background</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Build</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">WP Theme Anatomy</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Putting it Together</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Files</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sharing Your Theme</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Resources</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Guides</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Videos</a></li>
            </ul>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

JSFiddle Version: http://jsfiddle.net/j77mqm6q/1/